# What are the notes for the Warp Whistle?

Tags: super-mario-bros-3

I would like to stump one of my friends, who likes Super Mario. I would like to play the 6 notes that make up the Warp Whistle tune. Could someone please tell me the notes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.losdoggies.com/archives/132), the notes are the following:

> It begins on a D tone, goes up a whole tone to an E, then jumps up to another D an octave higher, and from there it descends chromatically to a B.

In the case you would be using the [fixed do solfège system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Fixed_do_solf.C3.A8ge), B corresponds to Si, C to Do, C# to Do#, D to Re and E to Mi.

Here is the sheet music:

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO much, Isuka. I am new to this site, and didn't know it was listed. I'm going to write down the notes, and see if my friend recognizes it. I appreciate it!  :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks again! The check mark is now green and I'll remember that the next time I post a question and have it answered.